Statistical measures for a list of dates
How do I calculate statistical measures such as Mean, Median, StandardDeviation for a list of dates?
Thank you for your comments and answers.

Clear["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[1];

(* I am on v12.2 so no `RandomDate` for me *)

dates = Table[DatePlus ["15th March 2024", RandomInteger[{-50, 50}]], 
    5] // Map[DateObject];

Mean@dates



If you have multiple years and are interested in "time of year", then converting to a Julian day (not to be confused with the function JulianDate) and then using formulas for the mean and variance of "circular statistics" is more appropriate.  A crude Julian day function is julianDay[date_] := DateDifference[DateObject[{DateValue[date, Year"] - 1, 12, 31}], date] // QuantityMagnitude.

Here are functions for date statistics that you can try with Mathematica 12.1. To compute mean, median and standard deviation,  use Mathematica statistics functions by converting dates to absolute time.
Note: With Mathematica 13.3 or later, statistics functions work with dates, for example, Mean[dates] returns a date result.
SeedRandom[1]; (* list of random dates *)
dates = Table[DatePlus["15th March 2024", RandomInteger[{-50, 50}]],
    5] // Map[DateObject];

Find the mean date using the mean of the list of dates converted with AbsoluteTime.
dateMean[dateList_] := FromAbsoluteTime[Mean[AbsoluteTime /@ dateList]]
dateMean[dates];
DateString[%, "DateTime"]
(* Monday 26 February 2024 19:12:00 *)

The median is the middle value of the list of dates when sorted in order. If the list is an odd number of dates, the median is the middle value. If the list has an even number of dates, the median is the average of the two middle values.
dateMedian[dateList_] := If[OddQ[Length@dateList],
  Sort[dateList][[(Length[dateList] + 1)/2]],
  dateMean@Sort[dateList][[Through[{Floor, Ceiling}
    [Median[Range[Length@dateList]]]]]]]
dateMedian[dates];
DateString[%, "DateTime"]
(* Thursday 8 February 2024 00:00:00 *)

Compute the standard deviation using the list of dates converted with AbsoluteTime. The result is a value in seconds. Convert seconds to minutes. Use this method as a template for other statistics, for example, change StandardDeviation to MeanDeviation, etc.
dateStandardDeviation[dateList_] := Quantity[
    StandardDeviation[AbsoluteTime /@ dateList],
  "Seconds"] ~ UnitConvert ~ "Minutes" // N
dateStandardDeviation[dates]
(* 54429.3 min *)


To do statistical calculations with dates, you may change the dates to days from the date to today. Then you get numbers and you can do your calculations. E.g.:
dates = Table[DatePlus["15th March 2024", RandomInteger[{-50, 50}]], 
   5] // Map[DateObject];
days = DayCount[#, Date[]] & /@ dates;
mean = Mean[days]
StandardDeviation[days]

1324/5
Sqrt[12647/10]


Getting mean back into the original units might be DateObject[DatePlus[Date[], -mean]].
